# Page not opening on host machine when link is opened with IP Address and throws Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: localhost, single-sign-on, saml, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to implement SSO on a hybris system using idP.
The link to the hybris is opened using a third service-

10.x.x.x:9002/samlsinglesignon/saml/yacceleratorstorefront/assisted-service/emulate/?customerId=&site=Electronics

But the page gives the following error:
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at https://10.x.x.x:9022/samlsinglesignon/saml/yacceleratorstorefront/assisted-service/emulate/?customerId=&site=Electronics might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

But the page opens when I replace the ip with localhost.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Did you add the address to the local "hosts" file ?

Comment: yes, the address is present in the hosts file.

Comment: Check on which interface the TCP socket is bound to.

On Linux do
netstat -tan | grep LISTEN | grep 9022

On Windows do

netstat -an | findstr LISTEN | findstr 9022